Problemas con tildes
Tengo un fichero en excel con textos de este estilo.
text <- c("RAMI? 1/2N Y CAJAL","RAMON Y CAJAL","SAN AGUSTI? 1/2N","SAN AGUSTÌN","LOS I? 1/2NGELES")


[1] "RAMI? 1/2N Y CAJAL" "RAMON Y CAJAL"     
[3] "SAN AGUSTI? 1/2N"   "SAN AGUSTIN"       
[5] "LOS I? 1/2NGELES"  

Es decir, el fallo viene de origen, no es al abrirlo con R.
Alguna idea para no tener que ir uno a uno?
text2  <- gsub("RAMI\\? 1\\/2N Y CAJAL", "RAMON Y CAJAL", text )  
text2  <- gsub("SAN AGUSTI\\? 1\\/2N", "SAN AGUSTIN", text2 ) 
text2  <- gsub("LOS I\\? 1\\/2NGELES", "LOS ANGELES", text2 )  

[1] "RAMON Y CAJAL" "RAMON Y CAJAL" "SAN AGUSTIN"  
[4] "SAN AGUSTIN"   "LOS ANGELES" 

No sé si existe alguna librería diseñada para esto.

El problema es que el código que eventualmente habría que reemplazar es el mismo en todas las vocales acentuadas:  I? 1/2  vale tanto para la Í,  la Á y la Ó. ¿cómo podemos saber a cual de ellas correspondería?. Se me ocurre tener un diccionario tipo RAE y validar si la palabra es RAMÓN, RAMÍN  o  RAMÁN pero dudo que resuelva todos los casos.

Trata de abrir el Excel de forma que reconozca que el texto contiene tildes o caracteres raros. He aquí un vídeo de cómo hacerlo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJOO3lssGhE
